# C# Чтение и запись русского текста из файлов

Tags: c#, файлы, кириллица, запись

> Необходимо создать программу, создающую корректный HTML_файл,
>   содержащий весь текст из файла_с_текстом в котором помечены жирным и
>   наклонным шрифтом все слова из файла_словаря.  HTML_файл должен
>   отображаться в любом Internet-браузере (IE, Firefox, Chrome и др.)
>   корректно, показывая весь текст, с выделением указанных слов.

При чтении из файла в котором находится текст на русском языке и записи его в html программа некорректно считывает текст и заменяет его на на:[image: Текст файла на русском языке]

В то же время программа работает правильно, если текст на английском языке:
[image: Текст файла на английском языке]

Как  изменить кодировку StreamReader на чтение кириллицы?

Comment: Емнип, стримридеру всё равно на кодировку, за неё отвечает уже логика преобразования потока в текст. 
И вроде должен быть готовый StringReader(TextReader), который очень много уже умеет из коробки.
А, ну и кодировок-то много, из поддерживающих русский на ум приходят Юникод и вариации, а также WIN-1251 и KOI-8R. Вам кто нужен?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код чтения текстового файла и записи HTML.

Comment: @ArmanHayots: Наоборот, `Stream`'у по барабану на кодировку, а вот `StreamReader` как раз и занимается переводом байтов в текст. `StringReader` тут не нужен -- это реализация `TextReader`'а, который читает _из строки_. С кодировкой да, непонятно. @Nikita, чем вы вообще смотрите исходный текст из файла_с_текстом и из файла_словаря?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как изменить кодировку StreamReader на чтение кириллицы?

```
// для чтения файла в ANSI-кодировке (Windows-1251 aka CP1251 в русскоязычной винде).
var sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default);

// для чтения файла в той же кодировке Windows-1251, любая винда.
var sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

// для чтения файла в OEM-кодировке (DOS, CP-866), любая винда.
var sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
```

Кроме этого, при записи HTML нужно записать его кодировку (UTF-8) в заголовке:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
...
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</HEAD><BODY>....
```

Как это лучше сделать, зависит от того, как вы формируете HTML-файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@AdressIN, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@AdressOUT);
            string start = "<!DOCTYPE html>" + '\n' + "<html>" + '\n' + "<head>" + '\n' + "<meta charset = \"utf-8\">" + '\n' + "<title>New Page</title>" + '\n' + "</head>" + '\n' + "<body>" + '\n' + "<p>";
            string end = "</p>" + '\n' + "</body>" + '\n' + "</html>";
            sw.WriteLine(start);
```

Comment: Похоже, всё получилось. Хорошо. Переводы строк `'\n'` непонятно, зачем обособлены, можно же их прямо в той же строке писать. Или verbatim string юзать http://pastebin.com/chFRwMBr